# Canvas is messing up Input.Touchcount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to implement Unity's pinch zoom: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/pinch-zoom which hinges on `Input.touchCount == 2`

I have another script where a character is controlled by a floating joystick (Unity asset store) attached to a canvas with this script in Update:

```
Vector3 moveVector = (Vector3.right * joystick.Horizontal + Vector3.forward * joystick.Vertical);

            if (moveVector != Vector3.zero)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveVector);
                transform.Translate(moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

            }
            anim.SetBool("run", (moveVector != Vector3.zero));
```

When I turn off this script, the pinch zoom works, but when it's on the character can move but no zoom. I printed out Input.touchcount and only got 1 and 0, no matter number of fingers.

I need both - so when I am zooming the character doesn't move, and vice versa. Are there canvas settings that could be blocking the touch count being > 1?

I tried putting the Character move script in

```
if(Input.touchCount < 2) {
    CharacterMove();
}
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: When you say you "turn off the script" are you disabling the *script component* or *the entire game object*?

Comment: @Draco18s the script